# htaccess redirect for a mvc pattern website?

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Above is the .htaccess file content that is used for frontend portion of a mvc pattern web site. My requirement:
changing

```
localhost/ecommerce/admin.php?url=site/login
```

into

```
localhost/ecommerce/admin/site/login
```

Here, 'site' represents the class name & 'login' represents the method name.
'admin' is supposed to indicate that the url represents backend portion of the web site.

Update: i'm not using any framework. anyway, does it matter?

Comment: Which framework you using ?

Comment: i'm not using any framework. anyway, does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/?$ $1.php?url=$2/$3 [L,QSA,PT]
```

Here is a good post about `RewriteRule`: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs